# How to copy Items from Datagrid to Listbox

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0

I have a listbox, datagrid and a Button. The data grid is populated with data from MS SQL. I want to be able to copy selected item(s) from the datagrid to listbox using the button. The code behind the button is

```
 private void btnAdd_click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        lstSelected.Items.Add(iFacilitiesDataGrid.SelectedItem.ToString());

    }
```

```xml
  //List Box in xaml
 <ListBox Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="7" Height="258" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,4,0,0" Name="lstSelected" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="236" />
```

For the datagrid

```xml
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" EnableRowVirtualization="True" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="7" Height="244" HorizontalAlignment="Left" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource iLocationICategoriesIFacilitiesViewSource}}" Margin="291,5,0,0" Name="iFacilitiesDataGrid" RowDetailsVisibilityMode="VisibleWhenSelected" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="247">
        <DataGrid.Columns>                
            <DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="facilityNameColumn" Header="Facility Name" Width="150">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=FacilityName}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="priceColumn" Binding="{Binding Path=Price}" Header="Price" Width="100" />

        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

Whenever I try to add item on the listbox, the item passed to  the listbox is "HM.IFacility" Where HM is the project name and IFacility the Table Name .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the instance of the object to enter the listbox, you cannot control the tostring method like you do:

```
lstSelected.Items.Add(iFacilitiesDataGrid.SelectedItem.ToString());
```

Instead, cast your selecteditem to the type:

```
lstSelected.Items.Add((HM.IFacility)iFacilitiesDataGrid.SelectedItem);
```

If you don't want the object to enter the listbox, but just some properties from that object, then you have to override the tostring in your object. If you don't do that, the tostring will give you the type of the object, like you said --> "HM.IFacility"

to override the tostring, put this in your object class:

```
public override string ToString() 
  {
     return property1 + " " + property2
  }
```

Where property1 and property2 are properties on your object class (like name, age, or id)

Comment: Thanks I casted my selected item to type and it worked 
`var r = ((IFacility)iFacilitiesDataGrid.SelectedItem).FacilityName

lstSelected.Items.Add(r);`

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a datatemplate for listbox as well. as you have created for DataGrid.  replace your listbox with below one and try again.

```
<ListBox Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="7" Height="258" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,4,0,0" Name="lstSelected" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="236" >
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=FacilityName}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>            
        </ListBox>
```

**Condition:** The data of DataGrid and ListBox must be same Type.

Comment: thanks, I did as you suggested but nothing was displayed on the listbox whenever you try to add selected items